# cannot set a variable to base on user input post method

Tags: php

Hello i´m trying to set info from a post method into a variable that sets a session named name the value that the user input. I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in F:\xampp\htdocs\Impossible game\index.php on line 18
>
> This is line 18: $session = $_POST['name'];

```
<form action="ms1.php" method="POST">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="Submit" value="Begin">
</form>
<?php
$session = $_POST['name']; 
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $session;
```

the previous error is gone and now this appears

> Notice: Undefined variable: session in F:\xampp\htdocs\Impossible game\index.php on line 23 below is line 23

```
 $_SESSION['name'] = $session;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the code is commented but untested. Please let me know if their are any issues.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){           //if the post has been set
        $session = $_POST['name'];       // Store the session in the variable
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name'] = $session;    // Store the name in a session for later use
header("location:index.php");    // Redirect the user     ##UPDATE##
    }   else    {
        //if post has not been set, show the form
    ?>
    <form action="ms1.php" method="POST">
    Name <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="Submit" value="Begin">
    </form>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: The code works , but it wont redirect since, on ms1.php i got http://pastie.org/3744452

Comment: and it displays Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in F:\xampp\htdocs\Impossible game\ms1.php on line 3 on ms1.php

Comment: this line is line 3:                                                             if(!session_is_registered(ms3)){

Comment: I have updated the code so that it will redirect, My indenting has messed up as im still learning how to actually display it properly on Stackoverflow, i hope you can look past it. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: it wont still redirect it´s something with these lines in ms1.php http://pastie.org/3745066

Comment: Make the "If" lowercase and try again, same goes with "Echo"

Comment: I changed this but still the same.

Comment: Your form is sending the data to ms1.php and then ms1.php is saying Sorry, it isnt set and is sending you back to index.php. Change the forms action to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the variable, index, offset is set before using them.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
   $session = $_POST['name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HTML part and the PHP part are 2 different things :

**index.html**

```
<form action="ms1.php" method="POST">
      Name <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="Submit" value="Begin">
</form>
```

**ms1.php**

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['name']))
             $session = $_POST['name']; 

     session_start();
     $_SESSION['name'] = $session;
?>
```

Comment: Ms1 stands for mission 1 and in index i the user to define a name and it ms 1 the users name will be echo. in mission 1 there is a mission to solve it just that i have to define the name.